# What will be the consequences for Israel if Israel is behind the Gaza hospital?

Tags: israel, united-nations, hamas, 2023-israel-hamas-war

Almost all (Real) human rights advocates and humanitarians and medias are trying to figure out who is right about **the terrorist attack on the Gaza hospital.**

I want to go one step further. It is clear what the consequences would be if it was Hamas.

**What will be the consequences for Israel if Israel is behind the Gaza hospital?**

I mean international law and organization like UN (not just verbal condemnation or condolences to the survivors and injured or calls for peace).

Obviously any resolution against Israel will be vetoed by the US. So I don't think there is any solution through the UN.

Answer (score 3):

Even those who blame Hamas on this attack do not think that the strike has been deliberate. They talk about the [failed rocket launch](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12643229/Israel-blast-Gaza-hospital-Palestine-video-rocket-misfire.html) that went horribly wrong.

In case it would be proven this definitely was the Israeli missile, then most likely something also went wrong, as there is no case at all how the civilian hospital could be the intended target. It would be a very bitter history but possible to swallow without shifting existing major views dramatically.

Proving that any of the sides have done this strike deliberately, with both target and consequences being as expected, would make a big harm for the reputation of that side. But just the intentions may be very difficult to prove.